# ConstraintLayout in Compose - how to center view in parent, but have it only fill the available space

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-constraintlayout

I have a ConstraintLayout which has three groups of views, one aligned to start, one to center and one to end. The one in the center should always be centered, but fill the available space to constraints.
My idea was to implement this with three rows, and using a horizontal chain, allow the middle one to fill to constraints. The middle one should just be constrained to the center of the parent, but the horizontal chain should allow them all not to overlap. However, if the views on either end have an uneven number of elements (e.g leading view is wider than the trailing one), the middle one ends up being off center.
I've seen a similar question for the view based ConstraintLayout, but the solution provided there ends up either not leaving enough space for the rows and just not displaying them, or my view gets off center.

The code:

```
        ConstraintLayout(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
        ) {
            val centerGuideline = createGuidelineFromStart(0.5f)

            Row(
                Modifier.constrainAs(main) {
                start.linkTo(centerGuideline)
                end.linkTo(centerGuideline)
                top.linkTo(parent.top)
                bottom.linkTo(parent.bottom)
                width = Dimension.wrapContent
            },
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
                ) {
                Divider(modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxHeight()
                    .width(2.dp), Color.Red)
            }
            Row(modifier = Modifier.constrainAs(leading) {
                start.linkTo(parent.start)
                top.linkTo(parent.top)
                end.linkTo(main.start)
                bottom.linkTo(parent.bottom)
                width = Dimension.wrapContent
            },
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Start) {

                Text("1", color = Color.White, fontSize = 14.sp)
                Text("2", color = Color.White, fontSize = 14.sp)
                Text("3", color = Color.White, fontSize = 14.sp)
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.size(42.dp))
            }

            Row(modifier = Modifier.constrainAs(trailing) {
                end.linkTo(parent.end)
                top.linkTo(parent.top)
                start.linkTo(main.end)
                bottom.linkTo(parent.bottom)
                width = Dimension.wrapContent

            },
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.End
            ) {
                Text("1", color = Color.White, fontSize = 14.sp)
                Text("2", color = Color.White, fontSize = 14.sp)
            }
            createHorizontalChain(
                leading, main, trailing,
                chainStyle = ChainStyle.SpreadInside
            )
}
```

How it ends up looking:
[image: The resulting view]

Note, I don't really have a divider in the middle, it's just there for easier visibility.

Comment: You want the middle view to fill available space but always be centered. Are you referring to the contents of the view being centered? (The view itself cannot always meet the two requirements.) If so, this middle view is a _TextView_?